# Why does Stable Baselines evaluation helper need the environment?

Tags: stable-baselines

A model in Stable Baselines needs an environment when it is created. e.g.

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
model = PPO2(MlpPolicy, env)
```

The evaluation helper also needs to have the environment specified. i.e.

```
mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=100)
```

What is the purpose of the environment specified in the evaluation helper if it is already in specified in the model? The environment it a mandatory parameter in both the model creation and the evaluation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to allow evaluation to be done on other environments than the one used to train the model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).